# Cordova 2.1.0 not getting included in the project after install

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cordova

I am creating an IOS app with cordova 2.1.0.
I installed cordova 2.1.0, by following the steps mentioned in  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iO

Now i made changes to files like AppDelegate.m, AppDelegate.h, etc. and www folder. When i see the physical folder structure in the project, the CordovaLib.xcodeproj does'nt get included in the project. Why is this happening? Why is it not getting included in the project. Every user will not download cordova and follow the steps.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "user will not download". The developer (you) have to downlod it nd create the app. Cordova is packaged within your *.ip file.

If the cordov project is not oincluded, you will be unabvle to build. If you cn build it, it is included.

If you don't want to handle the complete xcode project stuff, use [build.phonegap.com](http://build.phonegap.com)